# How to grep with multiple filters and print one by one?

Tags: linux, grep

I need count some patterns in logs, I can use

```
grep aaa ./logs | wc -l

grep bbb ./logs | wc -l
```

is there a easy way to do all things in one line? like

```
cat ./logs | grep -c aaa | grep -c bbb #didn't work.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
$ grep -oh -e aaa -e bbb ./logs | sort | uniq -c
```

From `man grep`, you can read:

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Also, for `-h`:

> -h, --no-filename
>                 Suppress the prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to
>   search.

The `-e` is used to match either one. Then, the results are sorted and counted using `uniq`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this will count the various strings that the patterns matches, not how many times each pattern matches. This makes a difference if the patterns are something other than plain strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-e PATTERN` flag.
In order to count how many lines contain **either or both** `aaa` or `bbb`:

```
grep -e aaa -e bbb ./logs | wc -l
```

If you want to count `aaa` and `bbb` separately, check the solution by Khaled.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/aaa/ { count["aaa"]++ }
     /bbb/ { count["bbb"]++ }
     END { for (pat in count) print count[pat], pat }'  file
```

This would update the count associated with the matching pattern whenever that pattern matches.  At the end, a list of counts and the corresponding pattern are outputted.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried with below command

veen:~$ `for i in aaa bbb; do perl -pne "s/\n/ /g" i.txt| awk -v i="$i" '{print gsub(i,$0)}';echo $i; done| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| awk '{print $2,$1}'`

output

veen:~$ `for i in aaa bbb; do perl -pne "s/\n/ /g" i.txt| awk -v i="$i" '{print gsub(i,$0)}';echo $i; done| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| awk '{print $2,$1}'`

```
aaa 1
bbb 2
```